# Melody for Studying Mishneh Torah

Tags: torah-study, rambam, music, yemenite-temani

When in Israel I went to a Temani synagogue named Beit Kenesseth haRambam and after services they study a bit of the Mishneh Torah but to my surprise the entire community chanted the Mishneh Torah in unison with a particular melody. Anyone know what melody that is or have recordings from online to share?

Comment: was it similar to this? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sFQaENLdq6U

Comment: @MoriDowidhYa3aqov Meeeh not really. But especially not at the 4 minute mark.

Comment: was more referring to 30sec on. thats how my kanis reads halokhoth from the mishno.

Comment: @MoriDowidhYa3aqov It could be it, but maybe I don't remember it well enough